# How can I refer to a class' attribure in the definition of a method of the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I refer to a class' attribure in the definition of a method of the class?

For example:

```
>>> class C:
...     a = 3
...     def f(self):
...         # nonlocal a  # nonlocal doesn't work                                                                                                                                                             
...         # a = 4  # create a local variable a in f                                                                                                                                                             
...         self.a = 4
... 
>>> c=C()
>>> C.a
3
>>> c.a
4
```

How can I     refer to `C.a`  in the definition of `C.f`?

- currently `self.a = 4` will create `c.a` which is different from `C.a`.
- If `self.a = 4` is replaced with `a = 4`, `a` will be a local variable in `C.f`, instead of `C.a`
- `nonlocal a` doesn't make `a` in `f` refer to `C.a`, and I wonder why?

Thanks.

---

Update:

In the definition of a class, when shall I qualify its attribute, and when shall I not? For example, I don't understand why the following is wrong:

```
>>> class C:
...     C.b=4
... 
>>> C.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'C' has no attribute 'b'
>>> C.C.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'C' has no attribute 'C'
```

Comment: Simple. Use `C.a = 4`.

Comment: Per your update: this is pretty esoteric.  When you are saying "C.b = 4" "C" doesn't exist yet.  You didn't get an error because you already had a different "C" class defined prior to executing this code. Type "del C" and then try again and you will get an error. You were updating the class variable for the old "C" class then redefining it with a new C class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the class itself:

```
C.a = 4
```

or potentially

```
self.__class__.a = 4
```

Comment: Thanks. When I define `C.a` by `a = 3`, why don't I have to write it as `C.a=3`? So inside the definition of a class, when can I refer to its attribute without qualifier and dot, and when do I have to?

Comment: `a` is initialized *before* the class object is created and bound to the name `C`. `__init__` is called *after* the class object is created, and the `class` statement does not create a scope visible to the body of `__init__`.

Comment: When you define `a` in the class, it's added to the class' namespace. That's syntatic. When you assign to `a` inside of a method, you need to address it using the class namespace.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks. How is `__init__` involved in the definition of class `C`? Isn't `__init__` only called when instantiating an instance of `C`? Also see my update to my post.

Comment: Sorry, my comment looks like I was thinking too much about a similar question. I mean `f`, not `__init__`.